# Issue: Mod rewrite with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently coding a campaign site and I'm sending a get variable called "id" to the index page like this: http://www.example.com/campaign/?id=4ed8854ff2a9

Rather than displaying the get variable, I'd like to display the link like this:
http://www.example.com/campaign/share/4ed8854ff2a9

This is my current .htaccess, generated by Wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /campaign/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /campaign/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How do I go about making this work, I've been trying to get it working the entire morning but without success.

Thanks in advance //
Jonathan

EDIT:
I just tried the below rewrite, but that did not work either.

```
RewriteRule ^share/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)?/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at this, just trying. nOt sure this is correct. please anybody corrects me if it is wrong.

```
RewriteRule /campaign/share/.+$ /campaign/?id=$1 [L]
```

if you rewriteBase is campaign. then it should be:

```
RewriteRule /share/.+$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried the code, but it did not work, unfortunately I can't tell why since I'm not very good at regexp and mod_rewrite.

Comment: @jonathan, see the updates, I hope somebody who is an expert can help here.

Comment: I tried the above, but I do not get any errors, I only get a 404 page, which gives me an indication that the rewrite did not work correctly.

Comment: what is the url when you get the 404page?

Comment: I tried this rewrite: "RewriteRule ^share/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)?/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA]", but it did not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: what about 'RewriteRule ^share/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /?id=$1 [QSA]', do you have index.php in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own try:

http://www.example.com/campaign/share/4ed8854ff2a9

should be rewritten to:

http://www.example.com/campaign/?id=4ed8854ff2a9

So your rewrite rules may look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule campaign/index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^campaign/share/([a-z0-9]+) /campaign/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

NB: I've removed `RewriteBase /campaign/` because I don't see any use for it with these rules.
Please tell me if it works.